# View Transition API does not work with document.createElement

Tags: javascript, css, view-transitions-api

I am trying to create transition between pages using transition API. The transition works correctly when using elements defined using HTML, but the elements disappear on transition when using `document.createElement` to create the elements.

There is no point in providing JSFiddle link as it is necessary to add these files to a folder, start web server, open `parent.html` and click the image to navigate to `child.html`.
Sorry for a lot of code, but I needed to provide everything as I am not sure where the problem is.
Thanks!

**parent.html**

```html
<script src="transition/utils.js"></script>
<script src="transition/script.js"></script>
<body>

<script>
    function add(){
        let a = document.createElement("a");
        a.setAttribute("href", "child.html");
        let img = document.createElement("img");
        img.setAttribute("src", "https://media.cnn.com/api/v1/images/stellar/prod/ap24002766263400.jpg?c=original");
        img.style.width = "300px";
        img.setAttribute("class", "img");
        a.appendChild(img);
        document.body.appendChild(a);
    }

    add();
</script>
</div>

<script src="transition/trans.js"></script>
</body>
```

**child.html**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="transition/style.css">
<script src="transition/utils.js"></script>
<script src="transition/script.js"></script>

<body>
    <div>
        <script>
            function add() {
                let a = document.createElement("a");
                a.setAttribute("href", "child.html");

                let img = document.createElement("img");
                img.setAttribute("src", "https://media.cnn.com/api/v1/images/stellar/prod/ap24002766263400.jpg?c=original");
                img.style.width = "700px";
                img.setAttribute("class", "img");
                a.appendChild(img);

                document.body.appendChild(a);
            }

            add();
        </script>
    </div>
    <script src="transition/trans.js"></script>
</body>
```

Here is my onLinkNavigate function that works when static elements are used:

**script.js**

```js
onLinkNavigate(async ({ fromPath, toPath }) => {
  console.log(toPath);
  console.log(fromPath);

  const navType = 'gallery-to-teacher';
  const content = await getPageContent(toPath);

  let targetThumbnail;

  let targetHeader;


  if (navType === "gallery-to-teacher") { 
    targetThumbnail = document.querySelector(".img");
    targetThumbnail.style.viewTransformName = "banner-img";
  }

  const transition = transitionHelper({
    updateDOM() {
      document.body.innerHTML = content;
    }
  });

  transition.finished.finally(() => {
    if (targetThumbnail) {
      targetThumbnail.style.viewTransitionName = "";
    }

    if (targetHeader) {
      targetHeader.style.viewTransitionName = "";
    }

  });
});
```

**utils.js**

```js
 async function getPageContent(url) {
    // This is a really scrappy way to do this.
    // Don't do this in production!
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const text = await response.text();
    // Particularly as it uses regexp
    return /<body[^>]*>([\w\W]*)<\/body>/.exec(text)[1];
  }
  
  function isBackNavigation(navigateEvent) {
    if (navigateEvent.navigationType === 'push' || navigateEvent.navigationType === 'replace') {
      return false;
    }
    if (
      navigateEvent.destination.index !== -1 &&
      navigateEvent.destination.index < navigation.currentEntry.index
    ) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
  
  // Intercept navigations
  // https://developer.chrome.com/docs/web-platform/navigation-api/
  // This is a naive usage of the navigation API, to keep things simple.
   async function onLinkNavigate(callback) {

    // not called on click!!!
      navigation.addEventListener('navigate', (event) => {
        const toUrl = new URL(event.destination.url);
        
        if (location.origin !== toUrl.origin) return;
        
        const fromPath = location.pathname;
        const isBack = isBackNavigation(event);
        
        event.intercept({
          handler() {
            if (event.info === 'ignore') return;
            
            callback({
              toPath: toUrl.pathname,
              fromPath,
              isBack,
            });
          },
        });
      });


   


  }
  
   function getLink(href) {
    console.warn(href);
    const fullLink = new URL(href, location.href).href;
    
    return [...document.querySelectorAll('a')].find((link) =>
      link.href === fullLink
    );
  }
  
  // This helper function returns a View-Transition-like object, even for browsers that don't support view transitions.
  // It won't do the transition in unsupported browsers, it'll act as if the transition is skipped.
  // It also makes it easier to add class names to the document element.
   function transitionHelper({
    skipTransition = false,
    classNames = '',
    updateDOM,
  }) {
    if (skipTransition || !document.startViewTransition) {
      const updateCallbackDone = Promise.resolve(updateDOM()).then(() => undefined);
  
      return {
        ready: Promise.reject(Error('View transitions unsupported')),
        domUpdated: updateCallbackDone,
        updateCallbackDone,
        finished: updateCallbackDone,
      };
    }
  
    const classNamesArray = classNames.split(/\s+/g).filter(Boolean);
  
    document.documentElement.classList.add(...classNamesArray);
  
    const transition = document.startViewTransition(updateDOM);
  
    transition.finished.finally(() =>
      document.documentElement.classList.remove(...classNamesArray)
    );
  
    return transition;
  }
```

**trans.js**

```js
const el = document.querySelector('.img');
el.style.transition = 'view-transition-name img';
el.style.contain = 'layout';
```